# How to get a list of user-agent with idle, status and url?

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm developing a minimal api using .net core and need a object who returns a list of Agents "User-Agent", with idle, status and url.

var user = context.Request.Headers["User-Agent"].ToString();

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Could you explain your purpose more clearly? do you want the object be your api's response?

Comment: Is more like how to return if idle? And the status , on or off? It’s a server.